# How to fix output of game board?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm making a small game of connect 4 and I'm trying to figure out how to update my game board once I get an input from a user? Once I update my board, the whole board is filled with X or O, and it does not update in the once spot in the column they choose. For example, when player selects col 1 it should put x at the bottom of col 1. The user should input the column 0-3 and once they do the letter X or O gets added to the bottom of the column they choose

example of output:

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

0 1 2 3

player x picks 1

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

0 X 0 0

0 1 2 3

player O picks 1

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

0 O 0 0

0 X 0 0

0 1 2 3

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int rows = 4;
  int columns = 4;
  char board[rows][columns];
  char player = 'X';

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      board[i][j] = ' ';
      printf("|%c|", board[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf(" 1  2  3  4\n");

  while (1) {

    printf("Player %c, make your move: ", player);
    scanf(" %d", & columns);

    for (int i = 4 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (board[i][columns] == ' ') {
        board[i][columns] = player;
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        board[i][j] = ' ';
        printf("|%c|", player);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf(" 1  2  3  4\n");

    if (player == 'X') {
      player = 'O';
    } else {
      player = 'X';
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes above your code and it is working correctly.I think there is an problem in your algorithm, you are assigning the whole column in the first for loop after while(1) and you are trying to compensate for this problem in the other for loops and assigning null to those parts, but this logic does not seem to work very well. The logic here is actually similar to the conventional traffic lights (pedestrian crossing) problem. First of all, you don't check if a row has already been assigned. You can do this in the simplest way, with a switch case or with if blocks. The code I'm going to share does this logically. It goes to the number of columns entered and assigns the player variable there if the number of rows is empty. The logic is quite simple, you can remove the switch case block and create a logic with for loops to create more professional code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int rows = 4;
  int columns = 4;
  char board[rows][columns];
  char player = 'X';
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      board[i][j] = ' ';
      printf("|%c|", board[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf(" 1  2  3  4\n");

  while (1) {

    printf("Player %c, make your move: ", player);
    scanf(" %d", &columns);

    switch (columns){
    case 1:
        if(board[3][0] == ' ')
            board[3][0] = player;
        else if(board[2][0] == ' ')
            board[2][0] = player;
        else if(board[1][0] == ' ')
            board[1][0] = player;
        else if(board[0][0] == ' ')
            board[0][0] = player;
    break;
    
    case 2:
        if(board[3][1] == ' ')
            board[3][1] = player;
        else if(board[2][1] == ' ')
            board[2][1] = player;
        else if(board[1][1] == ' ')
            board[1][1] = player;
        else if(board[0][1] == ' ')
            board[0][1] = player;
    break;
    
    case 3:
        if(board[3][2] == ' ')
            board[3][2] = player;
        else if(board[2][2] == ' ')
            board[2][2] = player;
        else if(board[1][2] == ' ')
            board[1][2] = player;
        else if(board[0][2] == ' ')
            board[0][2] = player;
    break;
    
    case 4:
        if(board[3][3] == ' ')
            board[3][3] = player;
        else if(board[2][3] == ' ')
            board[2][3] = player;
        else if(board[1][3] == ' ')
            board[1][3] = player;
        else if(board[0][3] == ' ')
            board[0][3] = player;
    break;

    
    default:
        printf("");//do nothing
 
}

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        printf("|%c|", board[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf(" 1  2  3  4\n");
    if (player == 'X') {
      player = 'O';
    } else {
      player = 'X';
    }
    
  }

  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Note: You have to write some control logic if you want to limit entered number in certain range like 1-4.